# AJAX and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

Im having an issue with the request below, for some reason I can seem to get the XML to display?

I've checked the URL and it displays fine, so im wondering whats going on?! Could anyone give me a hand? There should be something in the ResponseText not "NULL".

```
var url = "https://services.lexel.co.uk/paf/";

loadXMLDoc(url)

function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Where'd you get this sample?  It's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use AJAX to send a request to a different domain.

Comment: How can I use the XML post to get data from a different domain?

Comment: You need to write a server-side script on your domain that forwards the request to the other domain.

Comment: You can't. It's a XSS exploit possibility if it could. As SLaks said, use a server-side script.

Comment: What server-side language do you use?

Comment: @Josh the 3rd parameter of Send was "false" which means "Don't be asynchronous; block until we're done loading"  [In other words, what he did is valid]

Answer (score 0):

Here is some literature on cross-domain ajax: http://www.xul.fr/ajax/xdomainrequest.php
Cross domain request (XDR) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303(v=vs.85).aspx